# didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl-certificate, glassfish-4.1

I am trying to POST data to a bank website. 
What I have done:

1. I have installed certificate in glassfish that was issued to
   another 
         domain and use it in localhost.
2. Imported certificate to truststore

Then while submitting the form (POST) to bank website I get

`didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`

I have also tried loading .jks file from code and opening sslSocket, then use httpsUrlConnection to post data. This method works in standalone but while using throug application deployed in glassfish it gives 
`didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`

Code I have done:

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("E://keystore.jks"), "asdf".toCharArray());

        Enumeration<String> en = ks.aliases();
        int n = 0;
        PrivateKey privKey = null;
        Certificate certificate = null;
        Certificate[] certificates = null;
        String alias = "";
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String aliasKey = en.nextElement();
            System.out.println("aliaskey " + aliasKey);

            alias = aliasKey;

            privKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(aliasKey, "smart@123".toCharArray());
            System.out.println("privKey " + privKey);
            certificate = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey);
            System.out.println("certificate " + certificate);
            certificates = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);
            System.out.println("certificates " + certificates);
            System.out.println("Provider " + ks.getProvider().getName());


            try {


                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                kmf.init(ks, "asdf".toCharArray());
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

                SSLContext sslContext = null;
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);


                String url = "https://example.com/form";
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);

                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                    ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                }

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                String payload = "datas";

                OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                output.write(payload.getBytes());
                output.flush();


        }
```

Comment: did you manage solve this ?

Comment: Yes, I will share a repository if needed